# PROPERTY_NOTIFY in Eps32 BLE not recognised by InTheHand BLE

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

I'm using the following to initialise Characteristic in ESP32 BLE:

```
pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                                     CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                                     BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ
                                     | BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE
                                     | BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_NOTIFY
                                   );
```

On Windows Side (using InTheHand.BluetoothLE package), getting "The device does not recognize the command" on:

```
await serv.GetCharacteristicsAsync()
```

This only happens when the PROPERTY_NOTIFY flag is set on ESP32.

How else do I enable notifications?

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was because the device was paired and updating the descriptor to allow notifications wasn't taking.  Unpaired and retried and it works.
Sorry for wasting your time reading this.